# Windows 8.1 can not detect correctly adapter ram

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, display-adapter, system-info

I have Lenovo Flex 2-15 with 4GB of dedicated RAM, with GpuZ and Nvidia Control Panel correctly recognizing this, but `msinfo32` and `dxdiag` (Windows built-in unit) can't do this properly.

System Information (`msinfo32`) reports my Nvidia 840M GPU RAM only has 1GB when it actually has 4GB, and `dxdiag` reports monitor and current display mode as "N/A (WHQL drivers).

- I've installed the latest GPU driver and per my 2013 game setting report, my vRAM is only 32MB!

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Only one of those screenshots is correct because I can guarantee you, that you don't have 8GB video card. Would help to know what operating system your using.

Comment: @Ramhound It says Windows 8.1 in the title.

Comment: I expect the information to be stated in the question.

Comment: SEE THIS IMAGES TOO -  http://im54.gulfup.com/qDHLYO.jpg
 -  http://im43.gulfup.com/9Ao7xN.png  -

Comment: Why do you have both display adapters installed with drivers that can't possibly support switching between them

Comment: What's your suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug in Windows, explained in: 
 [`Msinfo32` Reports Unexpected Value for GPU RAM when GPU has >2GB of Dedicated Memory](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2495801/the-microsoft-system-information-msinfo32-exe-tool-reports-an-unexpect)